# Verify a temporary objects are created

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm in a java context and am using Mockito (but I'm not bound to it) for basic mocking needs.

I have code like this

```
public class AuditInfoSerializer {

    [..]

    public Map<String, Object> doStuff(Object a) {
        doOtherStuff("hello", new TempClass(someField, <someParams>));
        doOtherStuff("world", new TempClass(someField, <otherParams>));
        return getResult();
    }
}
```

and in a test I want to verify that there are two instances of `TempClass` created with the correct set of parameters when I call the `doStuff` method.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Why do you even care whether 2 instances of `TempClass` are created? It's an implementation detail. All you should care about is the `Map<String, Object>` that gets returned.

Comment: As to whether it's even possible, it will entirely depend on the implementation of `doOtherStuff`, which you have not provided. In it's current state, no.

Comment: Test the behavior, not the implementation.  For example, suppose `TempClass` is replaced with `ShinyAwesomeThingy`.  The internals do not matter as long as `getResult()` continues to return the same value for the same input.

Comment: Basically I wanted to cut repetitive work in my assertions, because `TempClass` is already fully tested and contributes a part of the result of `doStuff`. So I only wanted to make sure, that I call `TempClass` with the right parameters instead of repeating the same assertions in all `doStuff`-tests. But I guess something similar could be achieved with a test helper method that does the repetitive work. That way I wouldn't care about the implementation of `doStuff` and still cut the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to verify temporary data on the object under test.  You want to mock dependencies and assert the object under test behavior : that is with this input you have this output.
Mock verifying is a trade off for methods to mock that return nothing but only produces side effect.
So use it only as you don't have the choice.
In your unit test, what you want is asserting what the method to test returns that is `getResult()`.
Do that with `Assert.assertEquals(...)` not with `Mockito.verify(...)`.

Comment: A mock might be helpful. It depends what the parameter `Object a` is and how it's actually used. OP has unfortunately abstracted too many of the details away.

Comment: I didn't disagree with that. You asserted that a mock is not helpful: "To unit test AuditInfoSerializer I think that mock is not helpful" and you don't have enough information to make that claim

Comment: I don't go into the mock way because actually the OP wants to check the intermediary map with a mock, which is not a reason to mock. I addressed that. After I also agree it lacks of details to give a  perfectly suitable answer. But mocking to verify concept is just an anti pattern. You may verify as you need to mock, not in the other way.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to verify the calls to `TempClass` is that it is already tested and it contributes a part of the result of `doStuff`. So I wanted to get rid of asserting the same map key-values in all my tests of `doStuff`, but instead only test this subthingy `TempClass` once and in the higher level tests just make sure, that `TempClass` is called with the right parameters. But I think I see now that this isn't a good idea anyway (I don't want to know the implementation of `doStuff`in a test) and would better be achieved with some test helper method that does the repetitive work.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part I agree with @davidxxx's point about the mock verifying tradeoff. If you have a setup that allows you to make assertions about an outcome like a map that is created as a result, go for it!

From an API perspective `doStuff` is a simple straight-forward method: Throw something at it, get something back. The information you are interested in will be contained in the map (this would be your assertion).

There is a lot going on *under the hood* before `doStuff` returns something. Many people tend to want to break up encapsulation when testing stuff. They are constantly looking for ways to uncover what is going on behind the curtains. I believe that's totally natural. But of course, it's also an anti pattern. It doesn't matter what tool you (mis)use to break natural boundaries (mocking frameworks, custom reflection, "back doors" in your code base, etc). It is always wrong. As @Michael already pointed out, the call to `doOtherStuff` is indeed an implementation detail. Take the perspective of client code that makes a call to `doStuff`. Is it interested in *how* the map is created? I doubt it. This should also be your testing perspective.

One last thing about using verification in tests. I would like to mitigate the trade off statement. I really don't like the generalization here. Verification is not *always* the less attractive choice compared to *real* assertions:

```
// Valid test without any verifaction
@Test
void method_foo_returns_gibberish (@Mock SomeInput someInput) {

    // Maybe this is just to prevent an NPE ...
    when(someInput.readStuff()).thenReturn("bla");

    assertEquals("gibberish", Foo.foo(someInput));

}


// Test made possible by verification
@Test
void method_foo_is_readonly (@Mock SomeInput someInput) {

    Foo.foo(someInput);
    verify(someInput.readStuff());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedList);

}
```

This is just the most obvious example that I could think of. There is a fraction of BDD geniuses who strive to build their whole architecture around verification driven tests! [Here is an excellent article by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

When talking about testing, most of the time, there is no black and white. Using mocks and verification means writing *different* tests.

As always, it's about picking the right tool.